# combinatorics problem: two ways to solve same problem?

Tags: combinatorics

Currently i'm struggling alot with combinatorics.

The problem: **There are four siblings. What is the probability that at least two of them are born in the same month?**

This question asks to get two equal solutions using two ways.

- differ between siblings and count the variations how you can distribute the months on the 4 siblings
- don't differ between siblings and count the 4-element-combinations out of the 12-month-"alphabet"

I already understand that the first way is using ordered sampling and the second way is unordered sampling.

I came up with two solutions using $n=12$ and $k=4$

*First solution**: 
separating the individuals
since it is a "at least" - problem i want to subtract the cases in which there are no repetitions.

$ P_{1} = 1 - \frac{\frac{{n}!}{(n-k)!}}{n^k} \approx 0.43$

**Second solution**:

$P_2 = 1 - \frac{ {n \choose 4}}{{n + k -1 \choose k}} \approx 0.64$

${n \choose k}$: combinations i can choose of the 12 months without repetitions.

${n+k-1 \choose k}$: combinations i can choose of the months with repetitions.
so with these solutions i don't differ between the siblings. i just count the k-combinations with repetitions (all possible combinations) and the one without repetitions (the combination i want to substract).
Source: https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter2/2_1_4_unordered_with_replacement.php

here i take all the combinations with repetitions and subtract the the combinations without repetitions (n choose k).

Is any of these the correct solution? Why do they get different answers?
I know that the difference is that solution one is working with ordered and solution 2 with unordered sampling. But in my understanding it should still be the same since i only take relations (by division).

Answer (score 1):

The probability that at least two of them are born in the same month is equal to $1 -$ the probability that they are all four born in different months, and that's the probability that we will calculate (your first solution.)

The first one can be born in any month.  The probability that the second one is born in a different month is $11/12$.  Given this has occurred, the probability that the third one is born in a different month than either of the first two is $10/12$, and, similarly, the probability that the fourth is born in a different month than any of the first three is $9/12$.

Multiplying through and subtracting from one gives $0.427$, your first solution.

If you work through the algebra by expanding the choose functions into their component factorials and canceling where you can, you will, not surprisingly, see that they are not in fact the same.  This is, I strongly suspect, because you have misunderstood what "unordered sampling with replacement" in the link refers to.  In unordered sampling, the sample $(1,2,3,4)$ is considered the same as $(4,2,1,3)$, and similarly for other arrangements.  Thus, all the combinations with months $(1,2,3,4)$ taken together count a total of once in terms of what $n+k-1 \choose k$ evaluates to.  However, when you subtract $n \choose 4$ from that, you are subtracting the number of ordered samples without replacement.  You should be able to see that subtracting the number of ordered samples w/o replacement from the number of unordered samples with replacement may be a curiosity, but is unlikely to be useful, and certainly not for your application.

Comment: thanks alot for the answer. i edited the post to make i more clear (hope it worked).

Answer (score 0):

**(1) Focus on siblings.** Probability all different: First sibling chooses any of the 12 months, second chooses a different month with probability $11/12,$ third chooses non-repeated month with probability $10/12,$ similarly, probability id $9/12$ for the fourth. So $12(11)(10)(9)/12^4 = 0.5729167.$
Probability of at least one repeat: $1 - P(\text{All different})=0.4270833.$

Using R as a calculator:

```
prod(12:9)/12^4
[1] 0.5729167
1- prod(12:9)/12^4
[1] 0.4270833
```

**(2) Focus on months.** Probability all months different:  Choose 4 different months in ${12 \choose 4}$
different ways. These can be arranged in $4!$ ways. Total ordered ways of choosing $4$ months without restriction is $12^4.$ So 
$P(\text{All different}) = \frac{4!{12 \choose 4}}{12^4}= 0.5729167,$ as in part (1).

```
factorial(4)*choose(12,4)/12^4
[1] 0.5729167
```

$P(\text{At least one repeat}) = 1 - 0.5729167 = 0.4270833.$

**(3) Approximation by simulation.** In R, the code
`mos = sample(1:12, 4, rep=T)` selects four months at random from among 12 (with replacement). We do this a million times. For each sample of four months,
code `length(unique(mos))` finds the number $X$ of uniquely different months. Thus, the following simulation which approximates
$P(\text{At least one repeat}) \approx 0.427 \pm 0.001.$

```
set.seed(407)
x = replicate( 10^6, length(unique(sample(1:12,4,rep=T))) )
table(x)/10^6
x
        1        2        3        4 
 0.000591 0.044351 0.382570 0.572488 
 mean(x < 4)
[1] 0.427512             # aprx P(At least one repeat) = 0.42708
2*sd(x < 4)/sqrt(10^6)
[1] 0.0009894357         # aprx 95% margin of simulation error
mean(x);  2*sd(x)/sqrt(10^6)
[1] 3.526955
[1] 0.001168797
```

- The vector `x < 4` is a 'logical' vector with a million elements `TRUE` or `FALSE`; its `mean` is its proportion of `TRUE`'s.
- The average number of
  different birth months is $E(X) \approx 3.527 \pm 0.001.$
- The exact probability that all four siblings are born in the same month is $1/12^3
  = 0.0005787037,$ approximated here as $0.000591$ (again accurate to about three decimal places).

Here is a histogram of the number of the simulated proportions of the numbers of different birth months. The red circle shows the exact value, obtained above by
combinatorial methods.

[image]

Comment: thank alot. Can you give me hint why my second solution is not working?
it is just the version for unordered sampling. how do i know in this case i need to use the ordered one?

Comment: Sorry. don't understand what you're doing there. I used ordered samples in (2). It was easier for me to use $12^4$ in denom, and then numerator has to be ordered also.

Comment: ok. it's hard to express. i meant unordered. sorry for the confusion. i think it should also be possible to derive the solution using the ordered sampling equations. i got this from https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter2/2_1_4_unordered_with_replacement.php